# Date Condition of getting data from Server in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, json, web-services, ipad

I have a Server which will be pulling some changes in the form of `JSON Webservice` and that data I will download in my `iOS App`.
That Thing is done but problem is with `date`

I have not given any date condition `Neither in server side nor in my App` 
Whatever data will come from `JSON webservice` I will fetch in my `app` on `starting of the app`.

But I will also fetch the changes which I have already made.( Means previous day data or downloaded data)

Should I get the data for the today date from webserver? and IF i get the today date data then  what If one missed the todays data.

Should I check from the `App` side  that `"Which data is been downloaded "` 
I am not sure how do I give the condition to getting checked the previous version  and Where should the condition I should give ?

`Web Server side or the APP side`

Comment: I think,doing it server side will avoid your headache at device side...resulting to good performance at client side.

Comment: But what if one user has not downloaded the todays changes.. and tomorrow he wont get the yesterday changes..If i do it in server side

Comment: apply conditions as per requirment

Answer (score 0):

Is the intent for the app to see the newest stuff when it updates?  One approach is to pass a date on the request, which says "give me everything newer than this date".  The app would then remember the newest item it receives and use that date to make the next request.

To handle a first time case -- when the app has no newest item yet -- one approach is to send no date on the request.  The server would take this to mean "give me the newest items you have".

There's also the need to handle limits.  What if there are too many new items to be practically returned?  One idea is to return the limit, plus some indication that there are more.  Then the app can request again starting with the date of the newest item received, and so on.

If gaps are okay in the app's copy of the data, you can handle the limit case by treating as the first time case... just return the limit number of newest items.  If you do it this way, then the best first-time request would be to pass something like [NSDate distantPast]. So the server would always expect a date and always perform the same logic:

1. count items newer than the date passed on the request if there are
2. fewer than limit, fetch and return them if there are more than
3. limit, fetch and return limit items